# Installing Linux Software on SmartOS

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf, joyent, smartos

I am using a standard64 (Image 13.3.1) SmartOS machine from Joyent and I would like to install some software written for Linux.  The software (called wkhtmltopdf) is an HTML to PDF converter written in C++.  The software is [downloadable here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

How can I get this Linux 64 bit software to install and run on SmartOS?

Comment: shouldn't the KVM do this automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source code: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

You need to compile it on your machine. You might require some additional libraries. You can contact the authors for more info if the documentation doesn't help.

Comment: Has anyone successfully compiled this on SmartOS?

Comment: I don't know but this is what people generally do. Binaries are meant to run on specific architecture/OS. This is the best way if you have the source available.

Answer (score 0):

Joyent now supports Linux compatible instances (no VM) on their public cloud, so this should run fine just as is (a Linux binary).